# Jenkins - Read contents of secret file credential

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

How can I read the contents of a secret file in Jenkins when using the `credentials()` helper?

My use case is reading a .pem file in order to save a private key to the environment vars. Here's what I have so far:

```
environment {
    private_signing_key = credentials('private-key.pem')
}
```

Above, `env.private_signing_key` now stores the ABSOLUTE path to the .pem file on the local Jenkins filesystem, i.e. `/home/jenkins/my-workspace/@tmp/secretFiles/private-key.pem`. Of course, that doesn't help me that much because I need the actual contents of the file.

Examples online point to the usage of the `readFile()` helper, however this function only works with files of relative path, i.e. `@tmp/secretFiles/private-key.pem`, in order to prevent pipelines from reading other workspaces they shouldn't have access to.

My question:

Anyone have any idea how to read the contents of a secret file in such a way as I've described above?

Comment: you should store those credentials in global credentials on your jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Store those in Global credentials
Go in `Manage jenkins > Global credentials > add those with name "private-key.pem"`
Then you can use them in your jobs.
Thanks